# Spring Data JPA/Hibernate LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to hibernate/spring data JPA and occuring some problems when dealing with Foreign Keys.
I have the two table:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Job job;
}
@Entity
public class Job{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "job",
        cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I am trying to save one Job (job.Id) at the Users table. But if I am trying to peform a get(repository.getOne(id)) (via `...extends JPARepository<User,Long>` I am getting the following error:
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [backend.entity.User#193] - no Session`
Does anyone has a Tip how to fix it? I have read a lot on stackoverflow, but could not find out how to fix that.

Comment: Which version of spring data are you using? If it's higher than 5.0, you need to use `repository.findById(id)` instead of `repository.getOne(id)`.

Comment: Oh wow, that really fixed it. Thank you so much!